# How can i get the caller phone number on android PIE without using read call log permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-9.0-pie

I've built a cool app that uses the outgoing/incoming phone number
and send it some data.

The phone number retrieval works fine in all Android versions
except Android Pie (version 9).

In that version, I needed to add a `READ_CALL_LOG` permission in addition to the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission,
and then, the `PHONE_STATE` broadcast got called twice.
(the phone number is included only for the second time.)

But then I can't upload my app to Google Play because `READ_CALL_LOG` is a sensitive permission and my app goal is not listed in the allowed cases.

I believe that there are a lot of apps that make use of the incoming/outgoing phone number without the need to actually read the user's call logs.

My question is:
is there another way to retrieve phone numbers in Android Pie without using `READ_CALL_LOG`
or,
is there any way to bypass Google Play's restriction for that particular use case?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a Caller ID feature in my app (it is not the core functionality of the app), and I face the same problem. App is rejected from the Play Store. Any news about that?